# solving $\int \tan x \cdot \sin(2x)\,dx$ using substitution

Tags: integration

> $$\int \tan x \cdot \sin(2x)\,dx$$

I have simplify the expression to $\int 2\sin^2(x)\,dx$ how can I use substitution to solve it?

Comment: I believe you made a mistake in your arithmetic. $\tan x \cdot \sin(2x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \cdot (2\sin x \cos x) = 2 \sin^2x$.

Comment: sorry,I have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \tan x \sin(2x) dx$$
$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} 2 \sin x \cos x dx$$
$$2\int \sin^2(x) dx$$
Now use the fact that $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1-\cos2x}{2}$ to get
$$\int dx - \int \cos(2x) dx$$
(Note that the twos cancel). The first integral is trivial; $u=2x$ should solve the second, with $du = 2dx$ and therefore $\frac{du}{2} = dx$. Now just substitute in and remember the antiderivative of cosine!

Answer (score 1):

This reduces to finding the integral of $\sin^2{x}$ since $\sin{2x} = 2\sin{x}\cos{x}$,

HINT: $\sin^2{x} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos{2x})$